# Don’t close Dialog on pressing OK button of QMessageBox

Tags: qt, pyside, qmessagebox

I have called *QMessageBox()* like this:

```
class Main(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        self.view = QUiLoader().load("app.ui", self)
        self.view.show()
        self.functionA()
    ....
    functionA():
        try:
            ....
        except Exception:
            QMessageBox.critical(self, "Error", "System Failure")

def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    a = Main()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == "__main__"
    main()
```

When i click OK button of Message box it also closes my *Dialog*. How to avoid this ?

Comment: You will have to provide the code of your dialog. The messagebox won't be the culprit. You probably are calling the messagebox within your "accept()" slot or may have it connected to the signal, then just do not really accept it by not calling the dialogs slot.

Comment: If the dialog box should not close then what should be the action ?

Comment: @Pratham Message box should just close and user can resume working on dialog

Comment: I do not see a dialog in your code, only the message box.

Comment: Ignore my last comment, I see a dialog. Does the functionA() do anything else? like accepting the dialog? When is functionA() being called?

Comment: @SebastianLange functionA() just tries some condition and catch exception. What do you mwans by accepting dialog ? fnctionA() get called from __init__()

Comment: @pythonlearner, I think the problem is that you throw an exception in your dialog's constructor (I don't know how it called in Python) `__init__`, when the dialog is not fully constructed yet. Try to call the `functinA()` after the dialog construction is done.

Comment: The code works for me. Is there more to your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **QMessageBox** like this:

```
QMessageBox.critical(self.view, "Error", "System Failure")
```

Comment: This answer is only true for your special case which was not sufficiently documented in the question. Other people will very probably require other arguments to QMessageBox. As it is this question is not a good question for SO because others are unlikely to learn much from it.

Answer (score 1):

Your code example (slightly altered to make it run) works for me:

```
from PySide.QtGui import *

class Main(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.show()
        self.functionA()

    def functionA(self):
        try:
            raise Exception()
        except Exception:
            QMessageBox.critical(self, "Error", "System Failure")

app = QApplication([])
a = Main()
app.exec_()
```

You can press OK on the message box and the dialog will not be closed. You are probably doing something else too that causes the closing of the dialog.

Comment: Yes, i was doing something else too. So i updated the question and found solution as well

Comment: @Patrick: shame, you didn't write what it was. Having similar problem and not knowing what hit me.